# unable to Print custom Listview data in android

Tags: android

```
public class Setting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView listView1;
    ImageView backbutton;

    ArrayList<Notify> web = new ArrayList<Notify>();

    List<String> places = Arrays.asList("Item1", "item2", "item3", "Bing",
            "Itunes", "Wordpress", "Drupal", "Item1", "item2", "item3", "Bing",
            "Itunes", "Wordpress", "Drupal", "Item1", "item2", "item3", "Bing",
            "Itunes", "Wordpress", "Drupal");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        backbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Setting.this, web);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.backbutton) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my custom listview:

```
public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Activity context;
    ArrayList<Notify> web;

    public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<Notify> web) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingrowitem, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.rowcontact_txtName);

        txtTitle.setText(web.get(position).getWeb());
        // imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Notify.java class contain:

```
private String web;

public String getWeb() {
    return web;
}

public void setWeb(String web) {
    this.web = web;
}
```

}

I am trying to display data in list view but i don't know where am doing mistake even i have change string array to Array List so that i can display that 
text but its displaying blank item please help me and tell where am doing mistake .
 I am able to print data when i extend custom adapter to Array adapter while i want to display list view item using extending base adapter please tell me and  where is wrong

Comment: where you added data in your `web` ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps to if you want to get your `ListView` working

Create `Constructor` in your **Notify** model like

```
private String web;

public Notify(String web){
this.web=web;
}
//and getter / setter methods
```

Now, implement in your `Activity` like

```
List<Notify> web = new ArrayList<Notify>();
web.add(new Notify("Item1"));  
web.add(new Notify("Item2"));  
web.add(new Notify("Item3"));  
web.add(new Notify("Item4"));  
web.add(new Notify("Item5"));  

CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Setting.this, web);
```

Now, your `Adapter` seems like.

```
public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
private final Activity context;
priavte List<Notify> web;

public CustomList(Activity context, List<Notify> web) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingrowitem, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.rowcontact_txtName);

    txtTitle.setText(web.get(position).getWeb());
    // imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return web.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return web.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int ID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ID;
}
}
```

Comment: still not issue fixed

Comment: i have change this code then also not displaying data

Comment: where you added data in your `web ArrayList`?

Comment: In 
    List<String> places = Arrays.asList

Comment: Item1 i am unable to setweb() method

Comment: no its not working only adapter item display no value is displaying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66005/discussion-between-m-d-and-edge).